# C# Refactoring methods with same code except different function calls

Tags: c#, refactoring

The varying functions have different parameters and need to return values.

Example:

```
public T Foo(a, b, c, func_pointer)
{
   //common code 
   if(no errors)
   {
      return func_pointer(a, b, c)
   }
   //common code 
}

public T Foo(a, b, c, **d**, func_pointer)
{
   //common code 
   if(no errors)
   {
      return func_pointer(a, b, c, **d**)
   }
   //common code 
}
```

Is there anyway to avoid code duplication?

Comment: You should at least post sample code that compiles

Comment: ummm, common code after the return?

Comment: @KeithNicholas I updated the sample code

Comment: @RufusL I updated the sample code

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is to have the method with fewer arguments call the method with the next greater number of arguments, passing in default values for the missing args. Then the last method in the chain had the actual code, and does whatever is necessary with the default values.